# ZeroMQ design decisions

Tags: sockets, system, distributed, zeromq

In a REQ/REP socket, if the socket send a request to a dead (disconnected) node the message isn't delivered and stays in a message queue occupying memory. How can one clean these undelivered messages (let's say, messages that are in the queue for more than 1 minute)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to set the optional parameter `ZMQ_LINGER`:

> The ZMQ_LINGER option shall set the
>   linger period for the specified
>   socket. The linger period determines
>   how long pending messages which have
>   yet to be sent to a peer shall linger
>   in memory after a socket is closed
>   with zmq_close(3), and further affects
>   the termination of the socket's
>   context with zmq_term(3).

... for which a positive value will set a maximun time for message to be blocked in the queue.

See 
http://api.zeromq.org/2-1-1:zmq-setsockopt

Comment: Doesn't that only apply to the local socket (which hasn't been closed)? The question is about when the remote peer has terminated - but the local socket is still alive, surely?